# VSCode Settings.json is empty

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just install the latest version of the VS Code on my Win 10 x64, before that I install Python as well, but nothing else.
When I open the VS Code, it seems my Settings.json is empty (just my theme and zoom level are there).

I opened the Settings.json from settings with clicking on the icon that you can see in the bellow image (noted with a red circle in the top right side) or with searching the JSON keyword in the setting (result is the same)

[image]

But in this file I just have two lines of code which you can see in the below image:

[image]

But I think it has to bee a big file with lots of settings and so on, even I check this file in this path: `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json` and it was empty and just have this two lines of code.

- I install the python extension, Dracula theme and so on in my VS Code.

.

**Can you help in these questions:**

1. Do you know what is the problem?
2. How I can restore the default value of the setting? (in case they are missed)
3. I want to change the color of the comments in the python language because in this theme it is not easy for me to read them in files, I found I can change it from the Settings.json but mine is empty,

Comment: I have reported this issue to vscode's github: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/122920

Answer (score 0):

1. `settings.json` only contains those settings which override the default behaviors.
2. In order to restore the default settings (from .json) you have to delete the line. (You can also do it from the GUI)
3. I think the setting "`workbench.colorCustomizations`" is what you are searching for; try to Google it.

Answer (score 0):

You know what, `settings.json` being empty doesn't matter. It just means you didn't change many settings. `settings.json` stores **only the changes** in the settings and **not all** the settings.

If you want to change the color of comments, just add this in your `settings.json` file.

In this example, I used the color Red, i.e., `#FF0000`.

```
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "comments": "#FF0000"
    }
```

Don't forget to put the comma (`,`) after the last config.

Your resultant file should be like :

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme" : "Dracula",
    "window.zoomLevel" : 1,
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "comments": "#FF0000"
    }
}
```

Reminding again, don't forget to put the comma.

It should be `"window.zoomLevel" : 1,`